# Table width in view not run

Tags: views

i have problem with table width in view.
This is my setup of view:
[image: view_setup1]
[image: view_setup2]
in my style.css i have this:

```
.novinky-telo{
width:50px;
background-color:red;
owerflow:hidden;
}
```

but result is:
[image: result]

I need only 50px width, have you any ideas?

Comment: u need 50px width for what? the entire table? or just the field?

Comment: i need this only on left side in my first sidebar...but now i have across width of page. 50 px is example, i only have edit width, but it not working...

Comment: try my answer. if that don't do what you want, try customize field and label wrapper HTML (check 1 box below from your screenshot).

Comment: after customize field and label wrapper HTML not run...neither background color now not run :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the following in your class .novinky-telo

```
word-break: break-all;
```

Answer (score 1):

> owerflow:hidden;

you missed spelled overflow

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Comment: same problem :/

Comment: in your css, try `width: 50px !important; `

Comment: if you're caching your view don't forget to clear the cache.

Comment: I clearing cache after each update. width: 50px !important not run

Comment: http://www.apls.g6.cz/

Comment: you can delete your page link now =)

Comment: But now i have problem: the text was cutted...i need long text on more rows, not only on one cutted...ideas please?

Comment: its because you created a super long word. Brake them into spaces `1.Novinka 1.Novinka 1.Novinka`

Comment: see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fbum8w5m/2/) example, when you have a super long word, that's what happends.

Comment: realistically you will never have a super long word like that. `word-break: break-all;` shouldn't be necessary in the real world.

Comment: Here it is about 30 chars where the long word will cause trouble, so I think 30 char long word is rare especially in English, but in other languages it might be possible, e. g. German (http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/die-laengsten-woerter-im-dudenkorpus)

Comment: oh, I guess u got me there :p